# Question about changing dialog box layout

Tags: winforms, dialog

Hey, I just got started designing dialog boxes and windows forms, and I had a basic question.

When you use something like a windows installer, it has a next button, and when you click it the dialog completely changes layout in moving on to the next step. My question is, is this done by loading a completely new dialog box and getting rid of the previous one. Or is there some way of making a dialog with multiple pages/states (not sure what to call them).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Wizards are usually made using the [property sheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774540%28VS.85%29.aspx) control from the [Common Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775493%28VS.85%29.aspx) library. They do not create a new dialog, but use something similar to tab pages instead.